# React in Visual Studio without ASP.NET Core

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2019

Can you use Visual Studio to launch React applications without ASP.NET Core?

The template in Visual Studio creates a React application hosted on top of ASP.NET Core, but I have no need for ASP.NET and just want a pure React application.

But when the React application is a ASP.NET Core project then Visual Studio lets me run the project and it opens the project in the web browser for me.

But when the React application is standalone by itself without ASP.NET Core then Visual Studio does not show any run button.

Answer (score 0):

Open the React application folder with Visual Studio.
Open Package Manager Console and navigate to the project's root folder.
Type npm start or yarn start according to your project's structure

or

You can use a Visual Studio plugin like NPM Task Runner

Comment: Yes, I know about  the `npm start` command, but I wanted it to start when pressing F5 or the green ▶ "play" / "run" button.

Comment: I had the same problem. I found this solution.